# Alternative to Json.Net

Tags: json, json.net

just curious if there is an alternative solution to the Json.Net library from james newton king

Comment: Is there an issue with his library? I've used it before and it worked perfectly. Personally I'm used to GSon in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two from MS directly: JavaScriptSerializer and DataContractJsonSerializer. It depends on what version of the framework you're working with as to where they live.

That being said, JSON.Net from JNK is really easy to work with and does a good job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it's built into the BCL: [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created a new library for serializing and deserializing Json files into ADO.Net data objects.  In addition, the library can write raw Json files to disk, but still does not have the advanced object serialization and deserialization capabilities of the Json.Net library.  The name of my library is called Tiferix.Json and I have licensed it under LGPL.  I have published the library, along with the source code on my GitHub page.  The Tiferix.Json library is a work in progress, but I do believe it will eventually handle a number of the desired features that the Json.Net library provides.

As of now, if all you want to do is serialize your Json data to and from disk, the Tiferix.Json library will handle all these tasks via ADO.Net.  In addition, the Tiferix.Json library can utilize a Tiferix.Json ADO.Net schema, which will allow you to read and write Json schema to and from disk, before loading your Json data into the ADO.Net data objects.

The Tiferix.Json library also has a JsonDataWriter class that has much of the functionality of Json.Net library, but I still have not completed a JsonDataReader class to read raw Json into .Net variables.

I wrote the Tiferix.Json library because I wanted the ability to load and save Json data from .Net, but I didn't want to have to deal with the complexities and overhead of the Json.Net library.  Don't get me wrong, I find the Json.Net library to be comprehensive and has a wide variety of awesome features.  However, many times we do not need such a massive library to handle some of the basic needs for data manipulation.  The Json.Net library can become quite complex when you utilize some of the more in-depth features such as serializing/deserializing .NET objects, dynamic classes, anonymous types, etc.

Some other cool features that my Tiferix.Json library performs is the auto-identation of Json files you write and the ability to easily convert data from Json to XML and from XML to Json via ADO.Net data objects which is made easy by the classes provided in the library.

If you are interested to check out my .Net Json library you can download and view the source code of the library here:
[Tiferix.Json library](http://github.com/jontiefer/Tiferix.Json)

I am a bit limited on time now, but I am planning sometime in 2017 to have completed, a full Tiferix.Json object serialization and deserialization library and a JsonDataReader which can read raw Json data from files.  The library still requires a lot of work and I may also be open to other people who want to contribute on the project.